# Docker Volume Mounting issues with Ruby

Tags: ruby, docker

I have a testcase where I am running an instance of Ruby inside a windows docker container. I should stress the ruby script works fine outside of docker. When run inside the docker container the script also works fine, except when the target of the Ruby file's access is on a mounted volume. In which case I get an error. I can for the testcase of course work around this issue by copying the file, but that would cause complications for the real script that found this problem.

Here's an example transcript, cbh_test is the mounted volume

```
PS C:\> echo ""> bob
PS C:\> cp cbh_test\failer.rb .
PS C:\> C:\Ruby25-x64\bin\ruby.exe .\failer.rb
PS C:\> cd cbh_test
PS C:\cbh_test> echo ""> bob
PS C:\cbh_test> C:\Ruby25-x64\bin\ruby.exe .\failer.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
./failer.rb: Invalid argument @ rb_readlink - C:/cbh_test (Errno::EINVAL)
```

Docker instance invoked by:

```
docker run -it -v c:\Users\me\work\fred:c:\cbh_test  bob/failer  powershell
```

Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
COPY install_ruby.ps1 c:
RUN powershell c:\install_ruby.ps1
```

failer.rb:

```
def main(args)
    fragment = "bob"
    $tmp = File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), fragment), 'r+').read      
end
main($ARGV)
```

install_ruby.ps:

```
$RUBY_VERSION = "2.5.3-1"
$RUBY_RELEASE =  "2.5.3-1"


$url = ('https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/rubyinstaller-{0}/rubyinstaller-{1}-x64.exe'-f $RUBY_VERSION, $RUBY_RELEASE);
$exe = "ruby-install.exe"

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $exe; 
$args = "/silent /tasks='assocfiles,modpath'"
Start-Process -FilePath $exe -ArgumentList $args -PassThru -Wait
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried for several days and the only solution I was able to find to this problem was to use ltsc2019.